# How to change picture box image based on listbox selected item?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a listbox with items and I need the picture box to change image based on the selection in the list box.

The list box is populated by the Binding source display member.

```
using System.IO;
namespace CapstoneProject
{
    public partial class capstoneProjectForm : Form
{
    string picName;         

    public capstoneProjectForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;


        //string[] a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        string resFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources");

        foreach (string s in Directory.EnumerateFiles(resFolder, "*.jpg"))
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s))
            {

                dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Some caption about" + Path.GetFileName(s), s);
            }
        }
       ////foreach(string pic in a){

       //    MessageBox.Show(pic);

       //}


           // listBox.SelectedItem.ToString() = 

        // pictureBox.Image = CapstoneProject.Properties.Resources.batchat;

        // string dir = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        //  string imagePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dir);

       // pictureBox.Image =   

    }


    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)       {

    }

    private void btnAddWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form addWord = new addWord();
        addWord.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void btnEditWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form editWord = new editWord(listBox.SelectedIndex);            

        editWord.ShowDialog();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dictionaryDataSet1);

    }

    private void btnDeleteWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the selected Word?","Delete Word", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.dictionaryBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
            this.Validate();
            this.dictionaryBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dictionaryDataSet1);
        }      
    }

    private void capstoneProjectForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dictionaryDataSet1.Dictionary' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.dictionaryTableAdapter.Fill(this.dictionaryDataSet1.Dictionary);


       picName = (dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[listBox.SelectedIndex]["Image Name"].ToString());        

    }

    private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string description = (dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[listBox.SelectedIndex]["Description"].ToString());
        textBox.Text = description;              

    }

    private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: What will be the selected item? is that image path or something else

Comment: the list box is filled with words from a data base so say i click on the word apple in the list box, i need a picture of an apple to show in the picture box.

Comment: where you are saving the paths to the images?

Comment: What Grant said.  Why don't you add the image as a Tag to each listitem, then grab it when the selected index changes?

Comment: ok so i added the picture box databind to the tag then how do i grab it?